# custom function in smarty with closing tag

Tags: php, smarty

i know it is possible to write a custom function in smarty like `{myunction x="1" y="2"}`. but i wonder if theres any way to make a function that has an end `{myfunc}...{/myfunc}` and use the text in between  as a parameter ?

is there any way to do so ?

Comment: check http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl

Comment: check http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.block.functions.tpl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. These kinds of functions are called [blocks](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.block.functions.tpl).